# how to write if condition for column2 , column 3 of a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, group-by

I have CSV file which has 3 columns.

Here is what I have to do:

I want to write an `if` condition or whatever like `if Divi == 'core'` then I need the count of tags (distinct) without redundancy i.e ( two sand1 in the tag for core division should be considered as only one count).

One more if condition like `Div === saturn or core && type == dev` then same thing need to count the no of tags(distinct)

Can anyone help me out with this? As it was my idea.. any new ideas will be accepted if it satisfies requirement
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

First, load up your data with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
```

Second, format your data properly (you might have lower case/upper case data as in column 'Division' from your example)

for column in dataframe.columns:
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].lower()

If you want to count frequency just by one column you can:

```
dataframe['Division'].value_counts()
```

If you want to count by two columns you can:

```
dataframe.groupby(['Division','tag']).count()
```

Hope that helps 
edit:
While this wont give you just the count of when 2 conditions are met, which is what you asked for, it will give you a more 'complete' answer, showing the count for all two columns combinations